# KafkaConsumer.PlainSource Method (in C#.Net) Using large amount of CPU

Tags: c#, .net, akka-stream, akka.net

## below method using large amount of CPU can anyone help me to minimize the CPU usage with proper solution.

```
KafkaConsumer.PlainSource(
   consumerSettings, subscription)
     .RunForeach(result =>
      { 
          _ActorRef.Tell(result.Message.Value);
       }, materializer);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm running the [`SimpleProducer`](https://github.com/akkadotnet/Akka.Streams.Kafka/tree/dev/examples/SimpleProducer) and [`SimpleConsumer`](https://github.com/akkadotnet/Akka.Streams.Kafka/tree/dev/examples/SimpleConsumer) samples baked into the [Akka.Streams.Kafka repository](https://github.com/akkadotnet/Akka.Streams.Kafka) - and the `PlainSource` is designed in a nearly identical fashion to yours:

```
 KafkaConsumer.PlainSource(consumerSettings, subscription)
            .RunForeach(result =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Consumer: {result.Topic}/{result.Partition} {result.Offset}: {result.Message.Value}");
            }, materializer);
```

[image: Akka.Streams.Kafka PlainConsumer output]

Here's what my CPU utilization looks like - bearing in mind that the producer is continuously producing new events for my consumer:

[image: Akka.Streams.Kafka CPU output]

This is extremely low resource consumption - which is what Akka.Streams and all of its plugins (such as Kafka) provide out of the box.

Your setup has no backpressure support (since `IActorRef.Tell` is non-blocking) and therefore this stream is going to run *at full blast* inside your system. Whatever your actors are doing is probably what's responsible for high CPU utilization.

Your [other ticket is asking about how to add backpressure support to your Akka.Streams.Kafka application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75481070/how-to-implement-actor-ask-to-control-the-flow-of-data-at-a-certain-rate), so I'll help answer that too.