# How to Implement Actor.Ask to Control the flow of data at a certain rate

Tags: c#, .net, akka-stream, akka.net

I used below Method but it is using large amount of CPU so i want to use Actor.Ask instead of below method can anyone help me how to use Actor.Ask

```
KafkaConsumer.PlainSource(
   consumerSettings, subscription)
     .RunForeach(result =>
      { 
          _ActorRef.Tell(result.Message.Value);
       }, materializer);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

My previous answer, having the target actor backpressure via replying to the stream, is the most robust way of doing this. But since the OP indicated that their actor doesn't send back any kind of reply today, here's another way of doing it.

```
KafkaConsumer.PlainSource(
   consumerSettings, subscription)
     .Throttle(100, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 100, ThrottleMode.Shaping)
     .RunForeach(result =>
      { 
          _ActorRef.Tell(result.Message.Value);
       }, materializer);
```

That will enforce a maximum output limit of 100 messages per second - and once that threshold is reached the stage will backpressure Kafka in order to keep memory and CPU consumption low.

Comment: Our Application using Kafka Server as a data Source(data format: Xml or Json) so what happened if Kafka server
getting more than 100 records per second then how will this code processed for that ? 
can your code able to process more no of JSON or XML data in Kafka server?
what do you mean by 1 message? below one is our Json data act as input that we are using, will it count as one message? 
if Yes, then what happend if Kafka server receiving more than 100 messages per second

In our scenario Kafka server may receive more number of Json Or Xml data as input.

Comment: example(Json data):
{"Ref":"Total","Warn":[{"AsId":"SUN_1","Alts":[{"AlId":"SU-COM-NVT-001","TimeStamp":"1632810577000","Status":"Active"},{"AlId":"SU-COM-NVT-002","TimeStamp":"1632810577000","Status":"Inactive"}]},{"AsId":"SUN_2","Alts":[{"AlId":"SU-SUN-NVT-001","TimeStamp":"1632810577000","Status":"Active"},{"AlId":"SU-SUN-NVT-002","TimeStamp":"1632810577000","Status":"NotAvialable"}]}]}

Comment: Increase your throttle value to whatever is appropriate for your service. Like I mentioned earlier - backpressuring your query by having the actors reply back when they've completed processing is actually the right way to do this. You should really try to do that. Please mark one of my answers as correct.

Comment: After using your 2nd code still my CPU consumption is very high please help me on this because my priority is to reduce CPU usage.

Comment: @MdShahnewaz the `Ask<T>` answer is the best one to implement this. You have to introduce backpressure - having the `_ActorRef` reply back when it's finished processing a Kafka message so you can implement `Ask<T>` is the most robust way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You should refactor this to use a [`SelectAsync` stage in Akka.Streams](https://getakka.net/articles/streams/builtinstages.html#selectasync):

```
KafkaConsumer.PlainSource(
consumerSettings, subscription)
  .SelectAsync(10, result => {
  _ActorRef.Ask<TResponse>(result.Message.Value, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
  })
  .RunForeach(result => // will now be of type TResponse
  { 
      // do something with TResponse
   }, materializer);
```

This will give you backpressure support and will only allow up to 10 concurrent `Task<TResponse>`s to be outstanding at any given time. With `SelectAsync` invocation order is preserved - so the results from those tasks will be delivered downstream in the original order in which they were invoked. If you don't care about the order, use `SelectAsyncUnordered` instead for additional throughput.

Comment: I want to use _ActorRef.Tell(result.Message.Value); line inside RunForeach loop but i'm getting error for TResponse can u help me

Comment: getting error after using SelectAsync

Comment: Is `TResponse` the type of message you expect the actor to reply with?

Comment: We do not need TResponse. How to Implement logic without TResponse? As per our old method we are just calling "_ActorRef.Tell" method inside 'RunForeach' loop. now how to Implement logic with ActorRef.Ask method without TResponse?

Comment: `TResponse` is a generic parameter and should be whatever the type of reply is that can be sent back by your actor, which signals that the message from Kafka was successfully processed. You'd need to design your actor to reply back to the `Sender` property in order for this to work.

Comment: Here i'm getting error in `SelectAsync` method, vs code suggesting that we need to pass 3 more arguments inside `<>` like this :
`SelectAsync<ConsumeResult<null,string>, string, Akka.Streams.Kafka.Helpers.Icontrol>(int parallelism, Func<ConsumeResult<null,string>, Task<string>> asyncMapper)`
please tell me what i need to pass to remove that error.
and also i'm confused with `TResponse` please give some suggestions.

Comment: Read the documentation: https://getakka.net/articles/actors/receive-actor-api.html#ask-send-and-receive-future

Comment: I produced an entire YouTube video explaining your issue and how to fix it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0KYoIvrM9VY

Comment: I applied  backpressure support still my `CPU` utilization is more than `60%`. 
KafkaConsumer.PlainSource(
                consumerSettings, subscription)
                 .SelectAsyncUnordered(100, async result =>
                 {
                     var r = await _ActorRef.Ask<string>($"Consumer: {result.Topic}/{result.Partition} {result.Offset}: {result.Message.Value}");
                     return r;
                 })
                 .RunForeach(s => {}, materializer);

Comment: Decrease the value from `100` to something lower.

Comment: I tried after decreasing the value, still CPU utilization is more than 60%. we are using more than 10 Kafka Topics in our application. is there `CPU` usage depends on Kafka Topics?

Comment: It probably depends on how you're processing the data - reading from Kafka itself is inexpensive.